# How can we resolve @salesforce/apex modules in a standalone LWR?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-runtime

I'm attempting to build a project for a package that currently runs in Salesforce, that I'd like to host externally using my platform of choice. I've started by using `npm init lwr@latest`, and set up the project.

Next, I created a link such that `lwr/src/modules/c` points to `force-app/main/default/lwc`, which gives the appearance that, for example, `src/modules/c/myComponent` is `force-app/main/default/lwc/myComponent`. So far, so good. All of this code compiles just fine.

Now, however, I want to be able to add wire methods. I know how to write an LWR wire method, but I can't seem to resolve the modules. I ran `npm install @salesforce/apex`, which actually is a real module, but it just throws exceptions, so clearly it's meant to be an example.

What I can't seem to find is how to define a local module such that `@salesforce/apex/MyClass.MyMethod` will resolve to a real implementation, such as `src/apex/MyClass.MyMethod.js`. I also found, for example, `@lwrjs/label-module-provider`, for resolving modules, but it also doesn't seem to give me the insight I'm looking for.

Basically, I feel like there should be an easy way to cause `@salesforce/apex/MyClass.MyMethod` imports to resolve to a JS file that I can use to implement server calls on the stack I'm trying to use, but I just don't see an easy way to get this done.

Of course, I could use alternative patterns, such as renaming `@salesforce/apex` to something that fits the definition of a module, but that amounts to creating a script to deal with hundreds of lines of code to build a LWR-compatible module every time our Salesforce code changes, which feels inefficient.

Is there a way to create a system where our Salesforce package and LWR package can coexist using the same LWC files?

Comment: Did you mean @salesforce/apex or @salesforce/apex-node? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@salesforce/apex-node

Comment: @brovasi I want to be able to implement a system where, in LWR, when I do `import someMethod from '@salesforce/apex/SomeClass.someMethod'`, I can call a JavaScript function that will call my own API, allowing the source to be compatible between both projects at once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to create your own local package that simulates `@salesforce/apex`, you'll not find a module for it.

One approach is the following:

1. Create a `packages` folder
2. Create a node project under `packages`, it could be called `salesforce-apex-shim`
3. Make sure to name your new project `@salesforce/apex` in your package.json (example below)
4. In your main `package.json` add the following dependency `"@salesforce/apex": "file:packages/salesforce-apex-shim"` (example below)
5. Within your `salesforce-apex-shim` project, now you can create your JavaScript file `MyClass.MyMethod.js` exporting the method by default (example below)

**MyClass.MyMethod.js**

```js
export default function MyMethod() {
  return "Hello World";
}
```

**packages/salesforce-apex-shim/package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "@salesforce/apex",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "test-apex",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf __lwr_cache__",
    "dev": "lwr serve",
    "start": "lwr serve --mode prod",
    "start:compat": "lwr serve --mode compat",
    "start:prod-compat": "lwr serve --mode prod-compat"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@salesforce/apex": "file:packages/salesforce-apex-shim",
    "lwc": "2.17.0",
    "lwr": "0.8.8"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.15.4 <19"
  }
}
```

#### How to import?

Like usual!

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import MyMethod from '@salesforce/apex/MyClass.MyMethod'

export default class HelloWorldApp extends LightningElement {
  hello = 'Click to change';

  handleHello() {
   this.hello = MyMethod();
  }
}
```

I hope this solution works for you!

Comment: I had to add a step of `npm i -S path-to-shim` before this code would start working, but this answer ultimately led to the solution I needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to use the Salesforce Apex class methods in your Local Web Server (LWS) project using LWR modules. However, the @salesforce/apex modules are specific to the Salesforce environment, and they cannot be resolved outside the Salesforce platform.

One approach to resolving this issue would be to use a mock module to simulate the Apex calls in your LWS project. You can create a mock module that mimics the functionality of the Apex methods and returns hardcoded responses. This way, you can test and develop your LWS project without having to depend on the actual Apex methods.

To create a mock module for your Apex class methods, you can create a JavaScript file that exports the same functions and parameters as your Apex methods. For example, if you have an Apex method named MyClass.MyMethod, you can create a mock module in your LWS project named MyClass.MyMethod.js that exports the same function signature.

You can then use this mock module in your LWS project instead of the actual @salesforce/apex module. This way, your LWS project will still work with the same LWC files, and you can develop and test your project independently of the Salesforce platform.

Once you are ready to deploy your project to the Salesforce platform, you can replace the mock modules with the actual @salesforce/apex modules and test your project in the Salesforce environment.

Julian and my approaches achieve the same goal of resolving @salesforce/apex modules in a standalone LWR, but they take slightly different approaches. My approach involves customizing the LWR runtime environment, Julian approach involves creating a custom package to act as a shim for the @salesforce/apex module.

The solution I provided, which involves using resolve.alias in the webpack config, is more concise and does not require creating an additional local package. It may be a better fit for developers who prefer a simpler approach or have a smaller codebase.

Overall, both approaches seem valid, and the choice between them may depend on the specific requirements of the project and personal preferences.

Comment: Not a bad idea (+1), but this involved literally dozens of Apex methods that were to be implemented, and the idea was to have a lwr app that would run on a different server, while still allowing development of a single source that would work for this new server and Salesforce at the same time. Julian provided exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your contribution, and I hope we'll see you again soon!